# Run multiple elasticsearch service on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run multiple nodes on my pc (ubuntu) for learning purpose. I try to copy `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` and then rename it as `etc/init.d/elasticsearch1`. the both nodes run succesfully but it seems the both use the same config `etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` not `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch1.yml`.

here is my elasticsearch1 init.d file (since this file has no extension, did I call it right?) :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b8e21b46909b46f2cab

and this is the debug result `sudo service elasticsearch1 start`:

```
start-stop-daemon --start -b --user "elasticsearch" -c "elasticsearch" --pidfile "/var/run/elasticsearch1.pid" --exec  
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -- -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch1.pid --
default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch1.yml 
--default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch 
--default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch1 
--default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch1 
--default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch 
--default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
```

in the debug result, the config path is correct to config file I want. any idea why the both nodes use the same config?

Comment: Have you considered using docker to start multiple nodes side by side?  You may also want to take a look at this blog post [How to run multiple elasticsearch nodes on one machine](http://www.concept47.com/austin_web_developer_blog/elasticsearch/how-to-run-multiple-elasticsearch-nodes-on-one-machine/).  And of course from the source itself [Can I run multiple Elaticsearch nodes on the same machine?](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-run-multiple-elaticsearch-nodes-on-the-same-machine/67)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newer version of ubuntu I suspect that systemd is being used, which runs services in a different context. therefore your NODE variable is overlooked. Have a look at for example https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service for how to set up environment variables for systemd.

For complete details, see Fedora's documentation on [how to write a systemd script](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3ASystemd).

Comment: i did it please see gist link i gave above.

Comment: what version of ubuntu is being used ?

Comment: the debug result showed me the correct path and "$node" translated to number "1" as well.. I just doubt I missed some configurations that I need to change to make it works :)

Comment: then move to centOS :)